# Unable to send SMTP mail() from localhost

Tags: php

I m try to send mail from my localhost but it not work fine . I am given my code below . please have a look at the below code and please tell what the actual problem is . Thanks

mail Function I Used ->

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = SMTP
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = NULL

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path = NULL

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters = NULL

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
mail.log = "D:\xampp\apache\logs\php_mail.log"
```

php code Used ->

```
    <?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Getting error When Execute PHP code Above->

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "SMTP" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\xampp\htdocs\mail.php on line 43
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What localhost program are you using? For example WAMP, XAMPP or a local VM?

Comment: You need to specify the domain or IP address of the SMTP server. In your php.ini file is "SMTP" a reference to a local SMTP server you have actually setup? If not you will need to install and setup an SMTP server. You can download a free SMTP server from the web.

Comment: XAMPP comes with Pegasus Mercury SMTP server which you can fire up.

Comment: There is no way to use SMTP server directly ,without download SMTP Server .

Answer (score 3):

There is no mail server running on your SMTP port 25. You could use the SMTP server that comes with IIS or you could use something like http://www.xmailserver.org/ or http://www.hmailserver.com

Server Manager > Features (not Roles) > Right-click, Add > SMTP Server - then Configure IIS 7 SMTP to point to the local server.

Comment: I had to install the mailer first .

Comment: Yes you'll need to install the mailer first before you can send mail. As Imran Azad suggests in the comments XAMPP comes with an SMTP server you can use,

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple python script which could allow you to run a mail server on localhost in wamp, you dont have to change anything in php.ini.

```
import smtpd

import smtplib

import asyncore

class SMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Running smtp server on port 25"
        smtpd.SMTPServer.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def process_message(*args, **kwargs):
        to = args[3][0]
        msg = args[4]
        gmail_user = 'yourgmailhere'
        gmail_pwd = 'yourgmailpassword'
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
        smtpserver.ehlo()
        smtpserver.starttls()
        smtpserver.ehlo
        smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
        smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
        print 'sent to '+to
        pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    smtp_server = SMTPServer(('localhost', 25), None)
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        smtp_server.close()

#end of code
```

Note: I used args[3][0] and args[4] as to address and message as the args sent by my php mail() corresponded to an array of args[3][0] as receipent email